# How can I view the personal files on my laptop SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, data-recovery, storage

Last year my laptop stopped working and I had to revert to my old laptop I had lying around in the wardrobe. Finally In the last couple of weeks I ordered a SATA to USB 3.0 adapter so that I can finally recover my most important files, like photo's, videos, old school work and game saves. I finally got the adapter in the mail today and I got out my 320GB SSD that was In my broken laptop, than plugged it into my current laptop with the adapter to find my files and take them off. But when I tried to do this, I couldn't find ANY of the files created by myself! The SSD Isn't dead either because I still have all the normal folders like Program Files, Program Files (X86) and Users etc in the SSD.

So I've tried looking through all the folders I could (even the ones that obviously wouldn't have my stuff in it) And couldn't find ANYTHING, even when I access the Users folder, The only user in there Is called "Public" and it doesn't have anything useful in it, it just has the Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures and Videos folders in it but they contain nothing. From googling it, I figured out how to view hidden files, but when I un-hid the files, all the new files and folders weren't helpful at all. There was a new user folder that appeared called "Default" and in that folder I found the Roaming folder which is usually where Minecraft Saves and other folders are stored, but when I go in there, the only folder in there is called "Microsoft" and there is also nothing useful in there and the .Minecraft folder is nowhere to be seen.

So my question is does anyone know how I can find the files I'm looking for? I'm extremely desperate at this point to get my data back. Thank you so much If you can help in any way. My old laptop used Windows 10 and my current laptop also uses windows 10.

Comment: By "stopped working" do you mean a hardware failure, or do you mean broken Windows? (I kind of suspect that someone used the "Reset Windows" feature, which deleted all data and left just a clean install on the disk.)

Comment: If user1686 has right , maybe try to look if you have a file call windows.old at the the same root folder of  progammes files.

Comment: Does the removed drive have BitLocker enabled?

Comment: No, It was over 12 months ago so I can't remember the exact details but 1 of these 2 things happened from what I remember: 1. one day I turned it on after having only used it the day prior and when it turned on it said an error message that I can't remember now, or 2. When I pressed the power button it didn't do anything at all despite being charged fully. Than I went and did something stupid (Not something that should affect the SSD) I went and tried to

Comment: open it up to see if there was anything obvious wrong on the inside since I've had previous experience opening up electronic (just not laptops) and knew what I was doing but I was getting extremely impatient because there was 1 single screw on the back that would simply just keep spinning endlessly so I ended up trying to force it open (I was so stupid) and It ended up popping something off of the motherboard and the computer just straight up stopped working completely after that and won't even charge

Comment: And spikey_richie, could you please explain what BitLocker is because I don't know. Thanks

Comment: What I did to the computer shouldn't have affected the SSD, I think I may have even taken it out before ruining the MB. And the SSD definitely works because I'm able to access some of the folders like I said in the OG post.

Comment: user1686 I definitely didn't reset/format my drive, that's for sure and nobody else touched my laptop either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you've already tried searching but do try:
fastfilefinder (admin mode)
if u remember any names of files you had just search for it
also try enabling 'show hidden files'
it seems quite odd that ur files are missing, are you sure your laptop doesn't have multiple drives or something, maybe it has an nvme hidden somewhere?

Comment: I went to try out fastfilefinder but while I was setting it up, I'm so dumb, I don't know how I didn't notice this before, I mustn't have been paying attention because I realized that this whole time I was trying to use a random laptop Hard drive That my Mum gave me once a while back that she found I don't even remember where, but It was in the same place I thought I'd been keeping the SSD the whole time and it turns out I'm using the wrong drive. I have no idea where my SSD has disappeared though annoyingly :( So I figured out the problem, I really hope I find the SSD.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Should I mark my question as answered or delete the post?

Comment: answered would be the choice, hope u find that hard drive though, I always lose my usbs and get pretty upset about it, thankfully I found most of them